# Nomad Hadoop installation error "Failed to download artifact : getter subprocess failed: exit status 1"

Tags: hadoop, exec, nomad

I'm using Nomad v1.6.1 and I tried to run Hadoop cluster on nomad by downloading a binary file using "exec" driver. However, there's still showing an error " Failed to download artifact : getter subprocess failed: exit status 1 ", the sbin file in Hadoop package couldn't be downloaded either. Below is the log and the job file that I wrote:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGgui.png)

```
variables{
  hadoop_version="3.3.2"
  node1="nomad37"
  node2="nomad78"
  node3="nomad79"

  //core-site.xml
  hdfs_cluster_name = "dmpcluster"
  dfs_permission= "false"
  hadoop_tmp_dir= "local/data/hadoop/tmp/hadoop"
  journal_edit_dir= "local/data/journal/tmp/journal"

  //yarn-site.xml
  ha_status= "true"
  yarn_cluster_name= "dmpcluster"
  //yarn-site spec1
  yarn_scheduler_mem= "47104"
  yarn_scheduler_cpu= "24"
  yarn_node_mem= "47104"
  yarn_node_cpu= "24"
  pmem_check= "false"
  vmem_check= "false"
}

job "hadoop-test" {
    datacenters = ["dc1"]
    type = "service"
    update {
      max_parallel      = 3
      health_check      = "checks"
      min_healthy_time  = "10s"
      healthy_deadline  = "15m"
      progress_deadline = "20m"
      auto_revert       = true
      auto_promote      = true
      canary            = 1
      stagger           = "30s"
    }
   
    group "hadoop-test" {
        count = 1

        restart {
            attempts = 3
            interval = "3m"
            delay = "10s"
            mode = "fail"
        }

        affinity {
            attribute  = "${node.unique.name}"
            value     = "nomad78"
            weight    = 70
        }

        task "hd1" {
            driver = "exec"
            user="root"
            artifact {
        source = "https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-${var.hadoop_version}/hadoop-${var.hadoop_version}.tar.gz"
        destination = "local"
      }
      template{
        destination = "local/hadoop-${var.hadoop_version}/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"
        data = <<EOF
"{{key "conf/hdfs/core-site.xml"}}"
        EOF
      }
            template{
        destination = "local/hadoop-${var.hadoop_version}/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml"
        data = <<EOF
"{{key "conf/hdfs/yarn-site.xml"}}"
        EOF
      }
            template{
        destination = "local/hadoop-${var.hadoop_version}/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"
        data = <<EOF
"{{key "conf/hdfs/hdfs-site.xml"}}"
        EOF
      }
            template{
        destination = "local/hadoop-${var.hadoop_version}/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"
        data = <<EOF
"{{key "conf/hdfs/mapred-site.xml"}}"
        EOF
      }
            config {
                command = "local/hadoop-${var.hadoop_version}/bin/hdfs"
                args=[
                   "namenode",
                  "-format"
                ]          
            }

            resources {
                cpu = 800
                memory = 8192
        }
    }
}
}
```

Expect to see that downloading can be completed and running on nomad

Comment: 1) Download the tarball outside of Nomad and extract in a consistent location on disk for the worker 2) `hdfs namenode -format` should be ran outside of Nomad. Then you would use `hadoop namenode start` to actually run it